# How to halt a integrant system

Tags: clojure

Context: I'm trying to set up integrant so that I can stop and start my jetty server

I'm getting:
IllegalArgumentException Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.Var$Unbound  clojure.lang.RT.seqFrom (RT.java:542)

When trying to halt my integrant system.

My Code:

```
(defn handler [request]
{:status 200
 :headers {"Content-Type" "text/html"}
 :body "Hello World!"})

(def config
    {:handlers/system {:port 3000
                       :host "localhost"
                       :join? true
                       :http? true
                       :ssl? false}})

(defmethod ig/init-key :handlers/system [_ cfg]
  (jetty/run-jetty handler cfg))

(defmethod ig/halt-key! :handlers/system [_ server]
    (.stop server))

(defn start []
    (def sys (ig/init config)))

(defn stop []
    (ig/halt! sys))

(defn resume []
    (ig/resume config sys))

(defn reset []
    (stop)
    (start))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Using `def` inside a function is something of a code smell; it's only rarely, if ever, appropriate. Usually, you'd be better off with a top-level `(def sys (atom nil))`, and then `(reset sys (ig/init config))` inside your start function. (Of course, this means the other users would be `@sys`, not `sys`, to deref the atom's contents; thus, `(ig/halt! @sys)`, and you'd probably want to reset the contents to `nil` when doing so).

Comment: Or use alter-var-root like https://github.com/weavejester/integrant-repl does (which might also be the lib you want to use instead)

Comment: I've updated my code accordingly, thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the config where :join? was set to true. This was blocking the process and meant that after using ctrl + c in the repl, sys hadn't been set to the return value of (ig/init config), and so when stop was called it was attempting to call .stop on an unbound fn, causing the error mentioned in the OP.